# Detecting and extracting multiple bar codes in image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

As a part of my project, I have to develop a code where in if the image have multiple barcodes all should detected and then that area should be cropped to create a new image.

The code is as follows:

```
#### Code for BARCODE detection  ######
import cv,sys
imgco = cv.LoadImage('/home/agnihotri/barcode/JPEG/counterservice_03.jpg')
img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(imgco),8,1)
imgx = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
imgy = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8,1)

### Convert image to grayscale ###
cv.CvtColor(imgco,img,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

### Finding horizontal and vertical gradient ###

cv.Sobel(img,imgx,1,0,3)
cv.Abs(imgx,imgx)

cv.Sobel(img,imgy,0,1,3)
cv.Abs(imgy,imgy)

cv.Sub(imgx,imgy,imgx)
cv.ConvertScale(imgx,img)

### Low pass filtering ###
cv.Smooth(img,img,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN,7,7,0)

### Applying Threshold ###
cv.Threshold(img,thresh,100,255,cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

cv.Erode(thresh,thresh,None,2)
cv.Dilate(thresh,thresh,None,5)

### Contour finding with max. area ###
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contour = cv.FindContours(thresh, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
area = 0
while contour:
    max_area = cv.ContourArea(contour)
    if max_area>area:
        area = max_area
        bar = list(contour) 
    contour=contour.h_next()

### Draw bounding rectangles ###
bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(bar)
pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])
cv.Rectangle(imgco, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(0,255,255), 2)

cv.ShowImage('img',imgco)    
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

The input image is as follows:[image]

The output image is as follows:

[image]

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Do you need any help, or are you just sharing something?

Comment: Yes...i do need some help with the code.

Comment: So what's the actual problem, though? What are we supposed to do after we read your code & look at your input & output images?

Comment: Hey,  We need to be able to track both the bar codes and save them as different images after cropping.  As of now my code is able to detect single bar codes and crop them....but with multiple bar codes it detect 1 and does not work on another one.

Comment: @rahul_champ detect the first barcode, crop it, fill its bounding box with white (?), repeat the barcode detection...